# How to delete a line if the occurrence of a string is exactly once per line?

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

I need to delete all the lines which contains a string exactly once in the same line. I would keep the line if there is no match found or even if the string matches twice.

I am trying to delete the lines that contain the string "priority" and only when this string appears exactly once per line. Is there anyway to do it using awk or sed ? This command does not give the desired output `awk -F'priority' 'NF==1' filename`

Input file :

shopping_priority+brands,baby_priority_brands

shopping_priority+brands,baby_shopping_brands

men_shopping_local,women_shopping_local

Expected output:

```
shopping_priority+brands,baby_priority_brands
men_shopping_local,women_shopping_local
```

Update:
Now I want to check for multiple words instead of "priority" . For example, I also want to check for {priority,women,shopping} and delete the line if "priority" or "women" or "shopping" occurs only once in a line.The list of words to check can be expanded later.

Input:

shopping_priority+brands,baby_priority_brands

shopping_priority+brands,baby_shopping_brands

men_shopping_local,women_shopping_local

pla%20electronics_bfhrg_shopping,pla_electronics_shopping

Now my expected output should be :

pl%20electronics_bfhrg_shopping,pla_electronics_shopping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F"priority" 'NF!=2' file
shopping_priority+brands,baby_priority_brands
men_shopping_local,women_shopping_local
```

By setting Field Separator to `priority`, all line with one `priority` will have two fields.  `NF!=2` print all lines that do not have one `priority`

Comment: @jww OP wants to delete records that have **only one** priority, so this will work with three priorities as well

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/priority/{s//&/2;t;d}' file
```

If a line contains the required string and it does not exists at least twice in the same line, delete the line.